# Oracle Rest Data Service Installation error

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to install Oracle Rest Data service on Apex, while it installs It shows below error and exists.

```
Installing Oracle REST Data Services version 3.0.0.343.08.03
... Log file written to C:\ords\logs\ordsinstall_2015-01-16_111716_00946.log
... Verified database prerequisites
Jan 16, 2015 11:17:19 AM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner executeSQLScript
WARNING: Error executing script: ords_create_schema.sql Error: ORA-65096: invali
d common user or role name
ORA-06512: at line 5

 Refer to log file C:\ords\logs\ordsinstall_2015-01-16_111716_00946.log for deta
ils
```

Also at the end it shows following

```
        at oracle.dbtools.rt.config.setup.VerifySchema.execute(VerifySchema.java
:80)
        at oracle.dbtools.cmdline.DefaultCommand.execute(DefaultCommand.java:83)

        at oracle.dbtools.cmdline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:162)
        at oracle.dbtools.cmdline.Commands.main(Commands.java:133)
        at oracle.dbtools.cmdline.Commands.main(Commands.java:291)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: This question doesnot belong to this community

Comment: Did you get prompted to enter a username during the install? Maybe it's a 12c issue? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60806/oracle-12c-create-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set TWO_TASK environment variable before setting up your sample schema.

```
export TWO_TASK=ORCL
sqlplus sys/passwd@ORCL as sysdba  <-- Normal use
sqlplus sys/passwd as sysdba <-- automaticly uses @ORCL
```

When TWO_TASK is set, the client connections by default will use TNS and alias in your tnsnames.ora instead of local connection and ORACLE_SID.

[AskTom's What is TWO_TASK](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:89412348059)